# Update entity in foreach loop

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I need to check if ID in array exist in my database, if does i need to put some "flag" in one of columns but i have a problem with it.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
    $fields = curl_exec($ch);

    $reader = Reader::createFromString($fields, 'r')
        ->setDelimiter(',');

    $records = $reader->getRecords(['id_pr']);

    foreach ($records as $offset => $record) {
        $product = $this->productsRepository->findOneBy(['id_pr' => $record['id_pr']]);

This is where i need to update my DB, for each record i need to update 
column 'flag' by eg. '1' but i dont know how :(

    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

I have tried something like $product->setFlag(1); but i cant call to setters or getters

It give me error:  Call to a member function setFlag() on null

This is how my Products entity looks like:

```
class Products
{    

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id_pr;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $flag;

public function getIdPr(): ?int
{
    return $this->id_pr;
}

public function setIdPr(int $id_pr): self
{
    $this->id_pr = $id_pr;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFlag()
{
    return $this->flag;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $flag
 */
public function setFlag($flag): void
{
    $this->flag = $flag;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you call setters or getters? Can you show what errors you get? Maybe also show what your Product-entity looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($records as $offset => $record) {
    $product = $this->productsRepository->findOneBy(['id_pr' => $record['id_pr']]);
    if($product) {
        $product->setFlag($flagValue);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush(); //I'm assuming that you're in a controller
    }
}
```

Comment: `EntityManager::flush` should probably be called **after** the loop. Also: It's `getDoctrine()` (missing parenthesis)

Comment: Loop have started but PHPStorm doesn't detect setFlag method so i think it doesn't work anaway but i have another problem right now, i have over 144k records in my DB and loop gave me error: 
/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php on line 137
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /application/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/OutOfMemoryException.php on line 1  :(

Comment: @ccKep yep, missed parenthesis. What does `EntityManager::flush`? I'm not using sf4 yet, so don't know this one. @jakmen your memory issue is probably something else.

Comment: I just meant that you should probably be calling `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush()` **after** the loop, instead of inside of it. That's the call that actually issues all the queries to the database.

Comment: @jakmen This might be a worthwhile read for you: [Doctrine docs in batch processing](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html).

Comment: Also, in order for phpStorm to detect the return type just hint it using phpdoc (eg. put `/** @var Product */` in the line above your `$product =` call, provided your entity is called `Product` and you have the appropriate `use ...` statement for it in your file)